# How to Split the PDF in Android?

Tags: android, androidpdfviewer

I am working with pdfviewer in Android. That PDF will download full documents which contains 100 pages. Now I need to download single page wise and show it. Currenty I am using DjvuDroidCodecLibrary. So can anybody help me?

Comment: Is there a specific function call you are trying to understand?

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information, but just a quick search revealed the `getPage` method in [PdfDocument.java](http://code.google.com/p/vudroid/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/vudroid/pdfdroid/codec/PdfDocument.java).